# How to index and search for documents between two dates in LUCENE

Tags: java, lucene

I'm working on JAVA, 
Let's say I have a document with the fields
"name" and "date" and I would like to index the field date and search for all the documents
between date1 and date2
who have a solution please?

Comment: You should clarify your question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @RomanKonoval i want to know how to index a date field and how to search for documents that their dates are between two given dates

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to add document's date into your index:

   ```
   Date date = new Date();
   Document doc = new Document();
   doc.add(new Field("docDate", DateTools.timeToString(date, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
   ```
2. Now you can search using `RangeQuery`

   ```
   Query query = new TermRangeQuery("docDate", DateTools.timeToString(dateFrom, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE), DateTools.timeToString(dateTo, DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE), true, true);
   ```